# Viewing the Grassmannian as a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ with basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$. Let $G(k, V)$ the the set of $k$-dimensional vector subspaces of $V$. We can embed $G(k, V)$ into $\mathbb P^{\binom{n}{k}-1}$ by sending a subspace $W$ spanned by $v_1, \dots, v_k$ to the class of $v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k \in \mathbb P(\bigwedge^k V)$, which after expressed in the canonical basis as $v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k=\sum_{|I|=k} a_I e_I$, is sent to $[ \dots : a_I : \dots]$. It can be seen that a vector $w$ in $\bigwedge^k V$ is in the image of the Grassmannian iff the matrix of the linear map $\wedge w: V \to \bigwedge^{k+1} V$, given by $v \mapsto v \wedge w$, has rank $n-k$, or all $n-k+1$ minors vanish.

Why does this describe the Grassmannian as the intersection of the vanishing of **homogeneous** polynomials? It seems to me this only gives polynomials (not necessarily homogenous) in the $a_I$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are homogeneous. Determinants gives homogeneous polynomials. Silly me. Because:

[Determinant gives homogenous polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986919/determinant-gives-homogenous-polynomial/1986930#1986930)