# Determinant gives homogenous polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix. Suppose some number of entries are $0$, say $k$, and suppose the other entries are variables, indexed $a_1, \dots, a_{n^2-k}$. The zeros can be anywhere in the matrix.

After taking the determinant of $A$ do I get a homogeneous polynomial in the $a_i$? This is certainly true for the $2 \times 2$ case, seen by brute force.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I just realized what to do after posting this question. Silly me.

The determinant in $n^2$ variables gives a homogeneous polynomial. Setting some of the variables equal to zero just kills some term of the determinant, retaining the degree of terms of the variables not set equal to $0$.